# Delegate function, how to pass reference?

Tags: macos, delegates, swift2, xcode7

Thx to Austin who solved my problem, the updated correct code is now : 
(The following code describes the problem:)

```
import Cocoa

class MyViewController1 : NSViewController, myProtocol {

// Identifier MyViewController2ID is set in storyboard for class MyViewController2
lazy var myViewController2: NSViewController = {
    return self.storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController2ID")
        as! NSViewController
}()

// ViewController conforms to protocol
func myFunction() {
    // do something
}

// ... some action
// presenting new viewcontroller as sheet
// new controller is presented and is dismissed
// when self.dismissController(self) is called
// in MyViewController2

self.presentViewControllerAsSheet(self.myViewController2)
}

protocol myProtocol : class {
func myFunction()
}

// Identifier MyViewController2ID for class 
// MyViewController2 is set in storyboard
class MyViewController2 : NSViewController {

weak var delegate:myProtocol?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
     if let pvc = self.presentingViewController as? MyViewController1 {
        self.delegate = pvc
    }
 }
// function is activated
func someFunction() {
    self.delegate?.myFunction()
    self.dismissController(self)
   }

 }
```

MyViewController2 is presented by calling :

self.presentViewControllerAsSheet(self.myViewController2)

within MyViewController1 and is dismissed in MyViewController2 by calling self.dismisscontroller(self) in someFunction() ..

The problem is the delegate is nil... I dont know how to pass reference to delegate function?

When calling another viewcontroller bye segue the reference to delegate function is set within the segue. There are no segue to put a reference for the delegate function?

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

In the `viewDidLoad()` of MyViewController2, get the `presentingViewController` and set it to be the delegate.

```
// viewDidLoad - MyViewController2
if let pvc = self.presentingViewController as? MyViewController1 {
    self.delegate = pvc
}
```